# Sub- or Function Procedure not defined

Tags: macros, libreoffice

I am writing my first macro for Libre Office right now and I have come into a bit of a problem: My code throws the error: BASIC Runtime error; Sub- or Function procedure not defined.

The line with the "If Cells (RowCnt,ChkCol......) throws the error.
I've looked through other entries on here, but I could not find the error... can anyone help me?

```
REM  *****  BASIC  *****

Sub Zeilennausblenden_Nullsummen
BeginRow=4
EndRow = 46
ChkCol= D

For RowCnt = BeginRow To EndRow step 1
    If Cells(RowCnt,ChkCol).Value > 1 Then
        Cells(RowCnt,ChkCol).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End if
Next
End Sub
```

PS: The function should hide all rows in which an integer higher than "1" appears in column "D"

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what the code looks like in LibreOffice Basic (aka StarBasic):

```vb
Sub Zeilennausblenden_Nullsummen
    BeginRow=4
    EndRow = 46
    ChkCol= 3
    oSheet = ThisComponent.Sheets(0)
    For RowCnt = BeginRow To EndRow step 1
        oCell = oSheet.getCellByPosition(ChkCol,RowCnt)
        If oCell.Value > 1 Then
            oRow = oSheet.getRows().getByIndex(RowCnt)
            oRow.IsVisible = False
        End if
    Next
End Sub
```

I wasn't sure if BeginRow should be 3 or 4, because it's zero-based.  You can test it and decide.

Note that a macro is not necessary in order to accomplish this task.  The easiest way is to go to `Data -> More Filters -> Standard Filter`.

Comment: this helped me a lot thanks! I also didn't know about the Data/Filter option

Answer (score 1):

That's because `CELLS` isn't a StarBasic function.

It's VBA (different programming language). Some versions of OpenOffice support the use of it if a statement (`Option VBASupport 1`) is put in first line of source code.

Check the net for Andrew Pitonyak's "OpenOffice Macros Explained" document - very good for learning and available in German translation, too.

Comment: thanks. I put it in the first line but it didnt work - I used Libre Office Calc, switchting to the usual excel now... will give report.

Comment: Andrew's document is an excellent resource, but does not explain how to show and hide rows, as asked in the question.

Comment: Question was "why i have an error" :-)
But anyway - I checked my 3 copies of Andrew's document, and you're right ti the point it's not demonstrating hiding rows.
+1 for your example

Comment: Makes sense.  I guess we each answered different parts of the question.